# Debugging in key iterator sorting in Hashtable

Tags: java, sorting, data-structures, hashtable

I'm working on this assignment, which wants a phonebook using Hashtable which implements a Dictionary ADT interface.
My file is working completely without any errors but just one drawback! My key values from the hashtable are not getting sorted. When I look up for phonenumbers with certain combination of digits, they should be displayed in a sorted order.

I also tried using shell sort besides this quicksort but it doesn't seems to help.
Here is what I am trying:

```
public class KeyIterator implements Iterator<K> {
    private DictionaryNode[] nodes, n;
    private int index;
    long modCheck;
    private DictionaryNode[] quickSort(DictionaryNode array[]){         
        n=array;
        quickSort(0, n.length-1);
        return n;

    }
    private void quickSort(int left, int right){
        if(right-left<=0)
            return;
        DictionaryNode pivot=n[right];
        int partition=getPartition(left,right, pivot);
        quickSort(left,partition-1);
        quickSort(partition+1,right);
    }

    private int getPartition(int left, int right, DictionaryNode pivot){
        int lPtr=left-1;
        int rPtr=right;
        for(;;){
            while(n[++lPtr].compareTo(pivot)<0);
            while(rPtr>0 && n[--rPtr].compareTo(pivot)>0);
            if(lPtr>=rPtr)
                break;
            else swap(lPtr, rPtr);
        }
        swap(lPtr, right);
        return lPtr;
    }

    private void swap(int lPtr1, int rPtr2) {
        DictionaryNode temp=n[lPtr1];
        n[lPtr1]=n[rPtr2];
        n[rPtr2]=temp;

    }
    public KeyIterator() {
        nodes = new DictionaryNode[currentSize];
        index = 0;
        modCheck=modCount;
        int j = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < tableSize; i++){

            for (DictionaryNode n : list[i]) 
                nodes[j++] = n;
        }

         nodes = (DictionaryNode[]) quickSort(nodes);

    }
```

I'm not supposed to use any JAVA API's for the code.

Comment: What are tableSize and list[]? Don't see them declared or set.

Comment: The list[] is an unordered list and tableSize is an integer value for the size of table.

Comment: tableSize = (int) (maxSize * 13f);  //for a table that is nearly %30 larger

        list = new UnorderedList[tableSize];

Answer (score 0):

For easier debugging, you should modify your prefix increments in the loops. It tends to increment the counter first, then call the array element while the algorithm doesn't intend to do that.

For example:

From
        `while(n[++lPtr].compareTo(pivot)<0);`

To

`while(n[lPtr].compareTo(pivot)<0) 
             lPtr++;`

Also change `if (;;)` to `while (rPtr <= lPrt)` and get rid of

`if(lPtr>=rPtr)
         break;`

They just make it seem confusing to debug. I hope you can find some changes with this.